# Programmatically determine max size of SQL Server Express database

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008-r2, smo

Is there a way to determine the max size of a SQL Server Express database using SMO?

Or will I have to add code to say

```
if express then
  if sql2005 then 
    limit = 4gb 
  else 
    limit = 10gb
else
  limit = unlimited
end
```

Comment: just curious, what's the problem to add the code?

Comment: @urlreader The problem is that when the database reaches 9gb there is no prompt saying "Your database is 90% full, please consider deleting files, or upgrading your version of sql server"

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.database.size.aspx

Comment: @JeffO The Database.size property gives the size of the database, and the SpaceAvailable property gives how much empty space the database has